# IOS App - SomeTime Uitextfield "PASTE" command appear in top left corner

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield, iqkeyboardmanager

After Orientation change in device The PASTE menu is displayed on top-left of the screen and cannot be accessed. Please see Screenshot.

[image: Please check this screenshot]

How to display "PASTE" command above to textField?

Thank you!